# Select list not posting selected option to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I have a current invoice list model that I want to bind to a select list

```
public class InvoiceList
{
   public string InvoicerReference { get; set; }
   public Invoice SelectedInvoice{ get; set; }
   public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the drop down in the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Invoice", "Billing", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedInvoice, new SelectList(Model.Invoices, "invoiceReference", "InvoiceDisplay"))
    <input type="submit" id="btnSelectInvoice" />
}
```

However when I post to my controller the model is null

```
public ActionResult Invoice(InvoiceList invoiceReference)
{
    ....
    return View(invoiceList);
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
public Invoice SelectedInvoice{ get; set; }
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedInvoice
```

The `Html.DropDownListFor` expects that the first parameter be of the type of the `value` of the options.
So, if your `invoiceReference`, is, for example, an `int`, you would do this:

```
public class InvoiceList
{
   public string InvoicerReference { get; set; }
   public int SelectedInvoice{ get; set; }
   public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```